# serving image from server is slow

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a forum-like app, and I'm currently refining my server-side code. The issue arises when posts with images are served; it becomes very slow. Since I'm a beginner to this, I'm unsure whether my code meets the necessary standards and I might have made some mistakes. Therefore, I'm seeking improvements for it. So i will only provide the image processing part.

```
    const promiseArray = [];

    posts.forEach(post=>{
        post.images.forEach((image, index)=>{
            const fileExtension = path.extname(image);
            const imagePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                fs.readFile("images/posts_images/" + image, (error, data) => {
                    if (error) {
                        console.error('Error reading image file:', error);
                        reject(error);
                    } else {
                        // Convert image data to base64
                        const base64Image = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');
                        // Add the appropriate data URI scheme with file extension
                        post.images[index] = `data:image/${fileExtension.slice(1)};base64,${base64Image}`;
                        resolve();
                    }
                });
            });
            promiseArray.push(imagePromise);
        });
    });

    Promise.all(promiseArray)
    .then(() => {
        res.json(posts);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).send(error);
        console.error("One or more promises rejected:", error);
    });
```

Could someone confirm whether I'm on the right path with the code, or if I'm misunderstanding promises, or if there's a better way to serve posts with images?

Comment: cache the processed images, or load them separately

Comment: If you send the client the image information as URLs, with appropriate actions on the server to serve the images, then the client can at least cache the images (assuming they're relatively static). Also the surrounding post content can load and the images can show up as their individual HTTP requests complete.

Comment: Note that the base 64 version of an image is *bigger* than the plain image by itself.

Comment: Oh also if in addition to the image URLs you can send the image sizes, your client code can create `<img>` tags with correct sizes so that the layout won't jump around while the images load.

Comment: i will try to load the other stuff first and then make individual request for those images

Comment: by the way how to cache the images, i actually not fully understande this concept

Comment: @pond well with ordinary `<img>` tags, browsers issue GET requests to fetch the images from the given source URLs. But if the browser recognizes the URL as an image it has fetched in the past, it will not bother to make an HTTP request and instead will show the image from the cache on the client. It will basically show up instantly. (Cache control options from your server obviously affect the precise details of how that works.)

Comment: @Pointy ooh, that's the reason why it show up faster when i refresh the page